# Unreachable code in Java

Tags: java

I don't get what does "unreachable code" means ?

Here in the last line of my code `double probabilityOfWin = wins / (wins + loses);` it says unreachable code.

```
import java.util.Random;

 public class CrapsGame {
    public static final int GAMES = 9999;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random randomGenerator1 = new Random();
    Random randomGenerator2 = new Random();
    Random randomGenerator3 = new Random();
    Random randomGenerator4 = new Random();

    int dice1 = randomGenerator1.nextInt(6) + 1;
    int dice2 = randomGenerator2.nextInt(6) + 1;

    int comeoutSum = dice1 + dice2;
    int point = 0;

    // The comeout roll

    if (comeoutSum == 7 || comeoutSum == 12)
        System.out.println("wins");
    else if ( comeoutSum == 2 || comeoutSum == 3 || comeoutSum == 12)
        System.out.println("loses");
    else
         point = comeoutSum;

    int wins = 0;
    int loses = 0;


    while(GAMES <= 9999)
    {
        dice1 = randomGenerator3.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dice2 = randomGenerator4.nextInt(6) + 1;
        int sum = dice1 + dice2;

        if (sum == point)
            wins++;
        else if (sum == 7)
            loses++;
    }

    double probabilityOfWin = wins / (wins + loses);


}
```

}

Comment: That's because ` while(GAMES <= 9999)` will always be true

Comment: It's quite impressive that the compiler identifies this situation if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks guys. I forgot to modify `game`.

Comment: I believe the intention of your code was probably to have while( gameCount < GAMES )  maybe? and increment gameCount every time through the loop?

Comment: @MattCoubrough Yeah that was my intention.But why it's quite impressive ?

Comment: To clarify my earlier comment, its quite impressive that the compiler can perform analysis of your code to identify that while(GAMES < X) is the equivalent of while(true) and then warn you that a line of your code will never be reached. In the "old" days compilers weren't as good at giving feedback about these types of things.

Comment: As @dlev writes, it may only be because GAMES is marked as final, in which case it might not be as clever as I probably gave it credit for - but its still nice to know that the compiler tries to help you write correct code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop here:

```
while(GAMES <= 9999)
{
    ...
}
```

resolves to `while (true)` because the value of `GAMES` is never modified. So any code that comes after (in your case, `double probabilityOfWin = wins / (wins + loses);`) is deemed **unreachable**.

Comment: Note that GAMES *cannot* be modified as the current code stands because it is declared as static final

Comment: @MattCoubrough He asked what *unreachable code* means. How he wants to solve the problem (change while condition, change variable type, other) is up to OP. But yes, valid point.

Answer (score 0):

You did not make any change to the constant `GAME`. So `while` loop will never terminate. Last line of code is unreachable. 
Unreachable means the code never gets executed. For example,

```
return 15;
int a = 12;
```

Then the last line of code will not get executed because the function has already returned.